# What are the top 10 problems yet to solve in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, ranking

Can somebody answer that? It would be good if the answer comes with evidences or some research paper. I'm not asking for opinions

Comment: Such an answer will always be opinion based, except if you give an objective ranking criterion.

Comment: @moose Yes but I'm looking for not just an opinion. Maybe some research paper or rank as you suggested. Something like we are good with Face detection (exactly people achieved a 99.6% of performance) like in this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03832). However, the performance of X is Y% which is low, and people is trying hard to push that limit.

Comment: What you posted is just one of hundreds of papers in machine learning. Most of them have some kind of evaluation where they compare their results with other results. That is just how science works. But is computer vision more important than speech recognition? Is question understanding more important than recognizing emotions? - I don't think there is any meaningful ranking criterion. This means it is not possible to answer your question objectively, but only by opinion. And I can guarantee you that there isn't any trustworthy paper which makes a statement like "CV is more important than ASR)

Comment: @moose I don't agree my friend. Can't you say that having a 99.63% of performance in Face Recognitions makes that problem solved??? ImageNet performance a couple of years ago was around 60% now is 96%. You said that there are hundreds of papers in ML answering my question. Do you have a good and recent example?

Comment: Take any of http://arxiv.org/list/cs.CV/recent - e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4038

Comment: "Can't you say that having a 99.63% of performance in Face Recognitions makes that problem solved?" - No. There is still room to 100%. And less memory usage. And less time. Working on less training data. Making the algorithm simpler.

Comment: ML is the response to the problems that mathematics and later AI had with such *programs*. And yes I agree, this is my opinion and I'll have a hard time to collect some evidence for this conjecture.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar question to yours from 2013 on Quora. To my knowledge, the problems given in the post are still mostly unsolved. Here you can find the [link](http://www.quora.com/What-were-the-Top-10-problems-in-Machine-Learning-for-2013).

I think #9 is perhaps the greatest obstacle.  How can we create a machine that hears, sees, and learns like a human?  Just like a human child starts at zero and learns from his/her senses, perhaps that is the best way to create a truly intelligent machine.

Comment: I agree with you. It's very difficult to learn like a human. It's really curious that the most successful algorithms right now, which are deep learning, are not the same as how the humans learn. There was a very good paper of Rodney Brooks taking about this. I'll try to find it